# Running into a weird error when copying from an iseries import file

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am facing the below error when running a program that does a cpyfrmimpf cl command:

[image]

The copy command is simple and straight forward as shown below:

[image]

Can someone help me ?

Comment: not really a programming question.  Try serverfault or midrange.com mailing list.

Comment: You may have a damaged object.  Can you provide the full text for those messages by pressing F1 on each one?

Comment: I think QAOKL02A has to do with the system distribution directory.   I would capture the value of &PATH and then run CPYFRMIMPF from the command line. Try to get the error to occur that way.